# German address - regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a webcall that give me the following callback as string:

```
ZIPCODE | CITY | STREET NR | , |Phone Number with (Tel.) on the beginning
```

EXAMPLE1 :

```
83661 Lenggries Marktstr. 14, Tel. 08042 91860
```

I would like to ask the regex professionals if it would be possible to break them down into groups?
My best try at the moment is:

```
([0-9]{5})(\s[a-zA-Z].+)(\s[a-zA-Z].+)(\s.*)(\s.[0-9]*)(\s.[0-9]*)
```

which results in:

1. 83661
2. Lenggries
3. Marktstr. 14,
4. Tel.
5. 08042
6. 91860

This works for the sample above but is not a stable regex, for example:

EXAMPLE2:

```
83620 Feldkirchen-Westerham Aiblinger Str. 7, Tel. 08063 8562
```

results in:

1. 83620
2. Feldkirchen-Westerham Aiblinger
3. Str. 7,
4. Tel.
5. 08063
6. 8562

Maybe somebody can help me with this problem, I have no idea how to solve it. The data cannot be given in any other format either. :(

regards and thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: What if the city and the address both contain spaces? How would you know where the former ends and the latter starts?

Comment: This not possible because city and street may contain spaces (as @silkfire already wrote). In theory you could use a ZIP code database to lookup the city name but even this approach wouldn't work well in practice because if the city contains user input it may include typos or additional data (e.g. "Heidelberg Wieblingen").

Comment: Also note that there are addresses without a street name, with a street name but no number, with the street name part containing numbers (in Mannheim) etc. Regular expressions seem not a good fit for address validation.

Comment: Example of where the city match will not work: Frankfurt am Main

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`^(\d{5})\s*([a-zA-Z].+)(?=\b\d+,)(\d+).*Tel.\s([\d ]+)$`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V5USBR/2) in PCRE

See C# Code [Demo](https://ideone.com/WjVUvI)

Answer (score 0):

Check it in Python!

```
^[ \-0-9a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß.]+?\s+(\d+(\s?[a-zA-Z])?)\s*(?:$|\(|[A-Z]{2})\s+(\d{5})\s*(.+)
```

if you want to see the demo! [Click here](https://regex101.com/r/2Lty6Z/1)